# LDAP: Not authorized because not authenticated on setting up ldap on devise_ldap_authenticatable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ldap, redmine, devise-confirmable

I followed 'https://github.com/cschiewek/devise_ldap_authenticatable'

The error I got on Rails console

```
  LDAP: LDAP search yielded 0 matches
  LDAP: Not authorized because not authenticated.
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 19ms
```

I tried to run the ldap setting on another Rails app 'redmine'

### Redmine works

[image]

### ldap.yml

```
development:
  host: dc01.toshiba.tw
  port: 389
  attribute: sAMAccountName
  base: dc=toshiba,dc=tw
  admin_user: redmine.rd@toshiba.tw
  admin_password: adminredmine
  ssl: false
  # <<: *AUTHORIZATIONS
```

### Login page

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <div><%= f.label :email %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :email, autofocus: true %></div>
```

### devise.rb

```
Devise.setup do |config|
  # ==> LDAP Configuration 
  # config.ldap_logger = true
  config.ldap_create_user = true
  # config.ldap_update_password = true
  config.ldap_config = "#{Rails.root}/config/ldap.yml"
  # config.ldap_check_group_membership = false
  # config.ldap_check_attributes = true
  # config.ldap_use_admin_to_bind = true
  # config.ldap_ad_group_check = false
```

Comment: I know this has been a while , did you find a solution for this ?

Answer (score -1):

development:
  host: dc01.toshiba.tw
  port: 389
  attribute: sAMAccountName
  base: dc=toshiba,dc=tw
  admin_user: cn=redmine.rd,dc=toshiba,dc=tw
  admin_password: adminredmine
  ssl: false